# Swiping push notification away should open related news

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm new to iPhone development, but managed to receive push notifications in my iOS App. However, when I swipe away the incoming push notification, it just opens the app, but not the related post to the notification.

This is my code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
NSLog(@"Eine Nachricht ist angekommen, während die App aktiv ist");

NSString* alert = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"id"];

NSLog(@"Nachricht: %@", alert);

//This is to inform about new messages when the app is active

//UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
//if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
//    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Neuer Artikel" message:@"Nachricht" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
//    [alertView show];
//    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
NSLog(@"Device Token=%@", deviceToken);

NSUInteger theCount = [deviceToken length];
NSMutableString *theString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:2 * theCount];
unsigned char const *theBytes = [deviceToken bytes];

for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < theCount; ++i) {
    [theString appendFormat:@"%2.2x", theBytes[i]];
}

NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HERE_IS_MY_REGISTERING_URL",theString,theString];
NSLog(@"APNS URL : %@",url);

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Error bei der Registrierung");

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[self setApplicationDefaults];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
//This is the start of the push notification settings
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now, I have no Idea what to put where, to open a related post to a push notification...

Answer (score 5):

What do you expect? From your code, I can not see that you are providing any information about which post you want to be opened. Neither Apple, nor Xcode, or your code will know that by magic.

In your payload for the push notification, you must provide information what post you are referring to, and then read this information in your didReceiveRemoteNotification.

See: "Examples of JSON Payloads" here: [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)

Comment: And what is the code to read it in didReceiveRemoteNotifcation?

Comment: Just like you are reading the aps part of it: Where you now are using `NSString* alert = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];`, you would be using `id myInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"acme"];`, to stay in the Apple example

Comment: So, I simpy replace the string with the one mentioned?

Comment: Yes. If your payload is: `{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "New Post",
    },
    "postid" : "42424242"
}˚`, then you get the postid with `NSString * postid = [userInfo objectForKey:@"postid"];`